# Send command to detached screen and get the output

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnu-screen

I've been searching to find a way to send a command to a detached screen session. So far, so good. This is what I've come up with:

```
$ screen -S test -p 0 -X stuff 'command\n'
```

This command works as it should. But, I would like the output from it too, echoed straight in front of my eyes (no need for a `.log` file or something, I just want the output).

Using the `screen -L` command, is not an option.

Comment: Why does it have to be `screen`? Isn't this what child processes are made for?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a first in first out pipe:

```
mkfifo /tmp/test
```

Use a redirect operator. Redirect command's output to /tmp/test for example like this:

```
screen -S test -p 0 -X stuff 'command >/tmp/test\n'
```

Then in another shell

```
tail -f /tmp/test.
```

Note you may also want to redirect error messages using the [2>&1 operator](http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/Bash_operators#2.3E_or_2.3E.3E).

***Example***

As requested in the comments, let's assume we have a php script accepting user input and printing the server load on the input of "status":

```
# cat test.php
<?php
  $fp=fopen("php://stdin","r");
  while($line=stream_get_line($fp,65535,"\n")) 
  {
    if ($line=="status") {echo "load is stub";} 
  } 
  fclose($fp);
?>
```

You create two fifos:

```
 # mkfifo /tmp/fifoin /tmp/fifoout
```

You call a screen:

```
screen
```

In another console, let's call it console 2 you find out the name of your screen:

```
# screen -ls
There is a screen on:
        8023.pts-3.tweedleburg  (Attached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screens/S-root.
```

In console 2 you send the command to the screen:

```
 # screen -S 8023.pts-3.tweedleburg -p 0 -X stuff 'php test.php </tmp/fifoin >/tmp/fifoout\n'
```

you see the command appearing in the screen. Now in console 2 you can send commands to your php process:

```
echo "status" >/tmp/fifoin
```

and read from it:

```
# cat /tmp/fifoout
load is stub
```

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't work. If I'm sending a command to the creen like 'command >/tmp/test' the process must support the >/tmp/test syntax... And it doesn't.

Comment: For me it works, please note that I put "test" as your screen's name. You can find out your screen's name with the command screen -ls. Also, "command" should be replaced by your actual command, I tested with the command ls. Also, I tested with the bash shell.

Comment: I know that. And it doesn't work. For example, start a PHP script in a screen window, which, for example, responds to a command "status", which returns current server load for example. That's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: then you will need bidirectional pipes, I am adding this to my answer

Answer (score 6):

I have a python script that keeps track of numerous detached screen sessions and captures output from each (when utilization commands like *free, top -bn2, iostat* are periodically sent via 'stuff').

Instead of redirecting to a file and, thus, managing at least *one file per detached screen session*... I simply redirect to whatever tty/pts my parent session is using.

**Step #1:** Start a new screen session (with a human readable name) in detached-mode.

```
$ screen -dmS chad
```

**Step #2:** Send your commands (I'll use the 'free -g' command along with 'uname -r') via stuff. It is important to specify the window that you want to use (in our case, the first and only window) with -p.

```
$ screen -r chad -p0 -X stuff "free -g; uname -r"
```

**Step #3:** The above step only sends the command text. We need to also send a carriage return to this detached screen session to have the shell execute our command. The ASCII character 015 is a carriage return on most *nix systems.

```
$ screen -r chad -p0 -X eval "stuff \015"
```

**Step #4:** Redirect the output of our detached screen session to our current tty/pts:

```
$ screen -r chad -p0 -X hardcopy $(tty)
```

**The output of Step #4 will look something like this:**

```
$ free -g; uname -r
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:             7          1          6          0          0          0
-/+ buffers/cache:          0          7
Swap:            1          0          1
2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64
```

Although this seems a bit involved, the process is easily scriptable. With python, I can parse the output of Step #4 and capture only the data that I care about.

Choosing a simple scenario like grabbing IP details, I wrote an example script to demonstrate the concepts above. Feel free to replace and tinker as you see fit.

**Example python script to get IP details from a detached screen session:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pexpect, time

#spawn a new bash session
session = pexpect.spawn('/bin/bash')
#send screen commands
session.sendline('screen -dmS netIP')
session.sendline('screen -r netIP -p0 -X stuff "ifconfig eth0 | grep -v eth0 | head -1"')
session.sendline('screen -r netIP -p0 -X eval "stuff \\015"')
#give the command a chance to execute before reading the output of our detached screen
time.sleep(0.1)

#use the output of the uname command as our string to expect
session.sendline('screen -r netIP -p0 -X hardcopy $(tty); $(uname)')
session.expect('Linux')

#parse the output - only concerned with the 'inet' line
output = session.before.split('\n')
for o in output:
    if 'inet' in o:
        print o

#kill the screen
session.sendline('screen -r netIP -p0 -X quit')
time.sleep(0.1)

session.close()
```

**Above script in action:**

```
$ python screen-output-test.py 
      inet addr:192.168.1.201  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

Comment: I like this answer a lot better than the accepted one, because it doesn't rely on the screen being in "shell prompt" state, but works with whatever is running in that screen as well.

Comment: However, it requrires the output to fit on the screen. I found `screen -X logfile /tmp/something`; `screen -X log on`; `screen -X stuff "command param"`; `screen -X log off` to work even better in that scenario.

Answer (score -1):

```
screen -S myscreen

screen -R myscreen -X exec command
```

Example:

```
screen -R myscreen -X exec top
```